# CSV Module "UnicodeEncodeError" when using Dictwriter.writerows

Tags: python, macos, postgresql

I'm setting up a prod environment on a new Mac server that should mirror my dev environment.  The job runs without a hitch on my dev computer, but on the server I'm getting this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/share/Code/PycharmProjects/etl3/jira_scripts/jira_issues_incremental.py", line 189, in <module>
    writer.writerows(rows)
  File "/usr/local/bin/anaconda3/envs/etl3/lib/python3.5/csv.py", line 156, in writerows
    return self.writer.writerows(map(self._dict_to_list, rowdicts))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 1195: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This job is being run through the `Run Shell Script` terminal in the `Automator` App.  I've checked the `sys.defaultencoding()` in the `Automater` terminal, as well as on the machine itself.  Everything says `utf8`.  I've also checked the encoding in my `PostgreSQL` database, and that is also set to `UTF8`.  Here is my `open` statement for the file that the `Dictwriter` is writing to:

```
    with open(loadfile, 'w') as outf:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(
            f=outf,
            delimiter='|',
            fieldnames=fieldnames,
            extrasaction='ignore',
            escapechar=r'/',
            quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
        )
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

I'm a little stumped as to where to even start to track down this error since all the default encodings seem to be correct...  I should mention that this file is then copied to a `PostgreSQL` database using the `psycopg2.cursor.copy_from` command after, so the file should be written in a mode compatible with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify an encoding for your file, so the default codec is used for your system. Currently that is ASCII. See the [`open()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> In text mode, if *encoding* is not specified the encoding used is platform dependent: `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is called to get the current locale encoding.

Specify a different codec instead. UTF-8 would work:

```
with open(loadfile, 'w', encoding='utf8') as outf:
```

`sys.getdefaultencoding()` doesn't apply here; that's merely the default for unqualified `str.encode()` calls.